# get.Year with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got this very simple code in Google apps script:

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getYear();
var newEstimate = month + '/' + date + '/' + year;
```

For some reason, the 'year' is outputted as '121'. Any ideas?

Comment: Date().getYear() has been deprecated:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

Answer (score 2):

**Recommendation:**

You can try using [getFullYear](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp)() method

```
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = today.getFullYear();// use getFullYear() method
  var newEstimate = month + '/' + date + '/' + year;

  Logger.log(newEstimate);
```

Here's the result:

[image]

**Additional info:**

The [getYear()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_getyear.htm#:%7E:text=Javascript%20date%20getYear()%20method%20returns%20the%20year%20in%20the,digit%20or%204%2Ddigit%20year.) method returns the current year minus 1900. Thus, it's the reason why you're getting 121 result for 'year'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a recent change by Google. I was using the same function for years and only in the last few weeks did the result returned 121 for the year. It's always been the "FullYear" prior.